# Does Google Nexus 7 LTE has the integrated Portable Wi-Fi hotspot?

Tags: nexus-7, wifi-hotspot

The unlocked Google Nexus phones famously have the **Portable Wi-Fi hotspot** feature integrated right within the phone, and available for anyone's use, per my understanding, regardless of carrier support.

What about the tablets?  Would the 2013 Nexus 7 LTE tablet have a similar feature, similarly not being tied up to any carrier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I do not own a Nexus. So the answer does come from internet sources (XDA).

As per this [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2443680) these are some of the responses from the owners which indicates that the **Portable Wi-Fi Hotspot** settings is indeed present in the settings.

1. *The option for hotspot tether is there both before and after the system update.*
2. *Nexus 7 FHD LTE with T-Mobile sim has Tethering & Hotspot available but not with newly activated AT&T data plan sim. The Tethering feature disappeared in setting. When I re-insert T-Mobile sim that comes with the tablet, the mobile hotspot is available again in the settings.*

So, it is safe to assume, only if your carrier allows tethering or you have a tethering plan the option will appear in the settings menu.

Answer (score 1):

I have a brand new Google Nexus 7 (2013) LTE tablet, bought directly at a computer shop (no carrier-related) and I can confirm, that it comes with *Tethering & Hotspot* option available by the default.